# Can't run Anaconda in MacOS terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, anaconda, command-line-interface, conda

I installed Anaconda on MacOS. I tried to run the conda command in terminal, but I got the following error message:

```
****/Users/rodalbert/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
/Users/rodalbert/.bash_profile:export:3: not an identifier: 2018.12
➜  ~ /Users/rodalbert/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
/Users/rodalbert/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/rodalbert/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool: line 1: `bash --init-file <(echo "source activate /Users/rodalbert/anaconda3;")'
[Process completed]****
```

I can't find the problem. Does someone know what to do in this case?

Content of .bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/11/bin/psql:$PATH# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/rodalbert/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/rodalbert/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/rodalbert/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/rodalbert/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Comment: Please show the exact command that you run that generates this error. Thanks!

Comment: I´m not sure what command create this problem but i search in terminal history, and i find some few i suspect about:         `                                    `export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH  `

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin”   `  

`printf %q "$PATH”   `

Comment: No, what command do you run when you see that error message in the post?

Comment: I not remember now, but terminal show this message all each time i open:                              
Last login: Mon Feb  4 18:57:58 on ttys001
/Users/rodalbert/.bash_profile:export:3: not an identifier: 2018.12
➜  ~                                                   
`

Comment: Please post the entire contents of your `.bash_profile`

Comment: Post is done, I hope can help to solve this mess, thanks a lot [darthbith]

Comment: I'm facing same issue, What's the solution?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're using Zsh.

Before executing any command from within Anaconda Navigator, try opening your Terminal app and switching shell to bash: `chsh -s /bin/bash` then restart terminal.

After you're done with Anaconda, switch back to Zsh: `chsh -s /bin/zsh` then restart terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I used [MohammadChavos](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11334#issuecomment-546623923)'s solution, then conda can run on the terminal.

```
cd /path/to/anaconda/bin
./conda init zsh
or:
zsh conda init zsh
```

My case: cd opt/anaconda3/bin, then run: ./conda init zsh